# Installing a sectioned garage door that's slightly wider than the opening

Tags: garage, exterior, garage-door-opener, garage-door

I want to replace my non-power garage door (up-and-over type) with a 8x7 ft. sectional one that rolls on a track. This way I can park cars right up next to it outside and not worry about opening clearance like I do now.

[image]

The problem is the door opening is 92" wide, which I can probably widen to 94". The door I'm looking at buying is 96" wide. Since it doesn't open outward, does this matter? I think I have enough room to install the track on the inside and there's definitely enough headroom for the springs.

Am I out of luck or will a slightly wider door still work?

Comment: I have a 10 foot x 10 foot garage door, ordered as such. The actual door sections are 122" long. The overlap is designed to be there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sectional garage doors are mounted to the inside you will have enough room.

You may need to remove the wood the current springs are attached to and replace with 2x6s to the top of the opening to mount the track. Blocking may be needed above the door opening as well.

Basic answer to "Will it fit"...Yes, it will, with a little work.

Comment: Thanks! I am totally fine adding the 2x6s, in fact I'm pretty sure the installation instructions for the door tell you to do this. I'll be thrilled to finally replace the existing door.

Answer (score 2):

I am totally in conclusion with @RMDman solution, I Installed sectional doors for a security company, they actually prefered the door to be just wider than the brick work all wood work removed and the tracks mounted to the brick work, (for security).

So you have to give yourself room for thought now, **is 96" wide enough**   :)

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I didn't even consider that. I think with the addition of 2x6 planks on the sides, I should be okay. It'll probably look better, too!

Comment: @Synthetix, yes theres that consideration between security and the visual outcome of a project, alas security does NOT consider aesthetics relevant.